# Dynamically Load ImageButton image using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, android-imagebutton

I am trying to load a number of image buttons into a `ScrollView`. Here is the code I am using,

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        BitmapDrawable bdrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        btn.setBackground(bdrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
});
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.topMargin = 0;
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
btn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
btn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
scrollLayout.addView(btn);
```

But the images are not getting loaded as expected. Whats going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue? What do you mean by 'not getting loaded as expected'?